# How do I detect if a touch event has landed within an EditText?

Tags: android

I can get find getX(), and getY() both return a float.  But how do I detect if the coordinates of a TouchEvent e.get(), e.getY() are within the boundaries of the EditText UI element?  I notice getX() and getY() are floats but getHeight(), and getWidth() are int.  Not going to help with comparisons ...

Comment: What have you tried? I **highly** recommend reading the [OnTouchListener documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)...

Comment: What I have tried is something called 'think before you code'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do? If you only want to detect if your EditText is touched, add an OnTouchListener to the EditText... or even OnClickListener.

Edit: If you want to detect outside, you can detect touch event in the containing view, and then, given you have your EditText view:

```
Rect editTextRect = new Rect();
myEditText.getHitRect(editTextRect);

if (!editTextRect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
    Log.d("test", "touch not inside myEditText");
}
```

Or you add a touch listener both to the EditText and the container, and return false in the one of the EditText, this way it will be intercepted and not forwarded to the parent. So, all the touches you detect in the listener of the parent, will not belong to the EditText.

Comment: The inverse of that.  Detect if a touch event has occured outside the EditText.

Comment: Ok. I think this basically right. But I would like clarification on what the container will receive.  Debugging seems to indicate that the contained elements like EditText gobble their touch events and they do not bubble up to the container.  Every other element on the activity like check boxes etc also gobble (do not bubble up) the touch event that lands in their zone. Perhaps their is some setting in the manifest to tell a contained element to bubble its touch events or would you need to override a method to do this?

Comment: So what I am saying is your answer is correct if and only if you can guarantee that the event reaches the top container. Then its better than what i ended up doing which is to have touchEvent handler on each control plus on the container(activity)

Comment: ps I did a findViewById() on the linear layout of the activity and then registered it for the touch events.  It got only the events that did NOT land on a contained control like say another edit text or check box. If it landed on open space where there was no control than top level onTouch handler gets it.