# Android ListView unselect item

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an application that have a ListView. In this ListView, when I touch in one item the background color of this item changes, to show that the item is selected.

Howerver, the layout have an EditText too:

```
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/pratosListView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"/>

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/quantidadeEditText"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                style="@style/EditText"/>
```

and when I touch the EditText the item selected in ListView is unselected, in other words, the background color back to the original color. I don't want this happens.

This is my selector (list_item_selector.xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_list_selected"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_list_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_list_focused"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_list_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Here I set the background of the item (item_lista_pedidos.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_all_magim"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector">
.....
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the implementation of the click listener:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // salva a posicao do item selecionado
        lastPositionSelected = position;
        // salva o objeto relativo ao item selecionado
        servicoSelected = servicos.get(position);
        view.setSelected(true);
    }
```

Someone have some idea to avoid the item to be unselected when I touch in EditText?

Comment: please consider accepting an answer as the correct answer if it helped you

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! But didn't helped. I solved this in another way. I changed the attribute "state_focused" to "state_activated" on list_item_selector.xml and removed the line "view.setSelected(true);" from the onItemClick function. But, anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370721/how-do-i-detect-if-a-touch-event-has-landed-within-an-edittext), If you want to detect outside touch only outside of EditText, you can detect touch event in the containing view, and then, given you have your EditText view:

```
Rect editTextRect = new Rect();
myEditText.getHitRect(editTextRect);

if (!editTextRect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
    //touch was outside edittext
}
```

Or you add a touch listener both to the EditText and the container, and return false in the one of the EditText, this way it will be intercepted and not forwarded to the parent. So, all the touches you detect in the listener of the parent, will not belong to the EditText.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! But didn't helped. I solved this in another way. I changed the attribute "state_focused" to "state_activated" on list_item_selector.xml and removed the line "view.setSelected(true);" from the onItemClick function. But, anyway, thanks.